# Objective-C propreties and private variable

Tags: objective-c, syntax

I'm a debutant to objective-c and I don't understand something.
I practiced c++ so some practices are not instinctif ..

1)

```
@implementation Car {
    // Private instance variables
    double _odometer;
}
```

Why a private attribute is in the .m file ?

2)

```
@interface Car : NSObject {
    // Protected instance variables (not recommended)
}

@property (copy) NSString *model;

-(void)drive
```

a)It seems model is declared like an attribute, but why it's not recommended to do it in the @interface ?

b) why the drive method is not in the interface ?

3)

What if i'm not use function allocation for exemple for a NString and initialise it directly with @"..." ?

4)

I don't understand the difference between + and - before method declaration too..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Private parts of the class can be removed or renamed in future. Public ones cannot. It takes a couple seconds to change something from private to public if you ever need to. So obj-c developers usually choose to make everything private unless it needs to be public. Instance variables are almost never public, the only benefit of a public variable is when you run into performance issues, in which case we normally just use C/C++ code and avoid Obj-C altogether.

Comment: Only - methods exist in instances of the class. Every class also has a single object called the "class instance", which has all the + methods and none of the - methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.>Why a private attribute is in the .m file

Why not? Everything that is declared inside *.m is private because *.m file could not be imported (included) somewhere. In objective C you can declare instance variables in both files - *.h and *.m

2.a Recommended way is to use accessors (@properties in Objective C). For each property setter, getter and instance variable are generated. Default names for

```
@property (copy)NSString *str;
```

are:

```
- (void)setStr:(NSString*)obj; // setter
- (NSString*)str; //getter
NSString *_str; //instance variable
```

You can modify accessors names

```
@property (copy, setter = NewSetterName, getter = NewGetterName )NSString *str;
```

and instance variable name (should be done @implementation section)

```
@synthesize str = _newStingInstanceVariable;
```

Ofcource you can rewrite setters and getters that are generated by default.

2.b Interface is everything between `@implementation` and `@end`. `{}` area after @interface - is a place were you can declare instance variables.

3.It is ok for NSStrings

```
NSString *str = @"some text";
```

but for most classes it will not work as you expect:

```
NSMutableString *str = @"some text"; 
// You will receive warning here! And str will be NSString, not NSMutableString
```

4.**"+"** - class methods (static in C++), **"-"** - instance methods.

Comment: Ho thanks you so much. So
a)
using @properties permit to declare attribute and the use of synthesize ?
b) What represent the {} after the implementation ?

c) The way you explain things are not easy to find in the internet . Have you some links for me ?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check. If you are going to develop in Objective C you should read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210

Comment: @property just condenses 10 lines of code down into a single line. It creates a private instance variable and public methods to read and write to it.

Comment: Sankyu but @synthesize running = _running;  , why we add an _ here ?

Comment: @Pépito the _ is there so that you can use `running` as a variable throughout your code, it's just to avoid naming conflicts. You almost never need to type `_running` in your code, you always use `self.running` instead. Normally `@synthesize` line of code isn't needed, it was in older versions of Obj-C  but now it's only used when the default behaviour needs to be changed. All of this stuff is convention, not part of the language syntax. Obj-C lets you code things in almost any way you want, but everyone generally agrees to do things the same way.

Comment: ok if I understand, when I'm doing @propreties model, in Xcode recent version , it synthesize automatically , the getter is self.model, the setter is setModel and the attribute name is _model ?

Comment: @Pépito, yes. You are right. And you can use setter explicitly `[self setModel:newModel]` or implicitly `self.model = newModel`

Answer (score 0):

There's a general principle in programming that you should make the smallest possible amount of information available to the outside. Anything that's in the .h file, anyone in the world can see, access, and mess up. If there's something wrong with an _odometer and it is in the header file, you have to go through *all* of your source code to find if something is using it wrong. If it's only in the .m file, you know that if there's a problem, it is in the .m file.

The other reason to not make things public is that you are free to change them if nobody knows about them. For some reason, you decide next month that having _odometer wasn't a good idea in the first place. By now three programmers have changed a dozen files to use _odometer because it was there. So removing that _odometer is now a lot, lot of work. If it was never in the .h file, nobody is using it so you only need to change your own .m file.